# input value se resetea al valor original

Tags: javascript, html

estoy tratando de modificar el valor de un input usando Javascript pero luego de modificarlo si hago click en enviar o en otro input mi valor ingresado se borra.

Estoy utilizando este codigo:

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("day");
inputElement.value = "1";
```

Alguien sabe que podrá ser, si me estoy olvidando algo o si el sitio web utiliza alguna proteccion para que no pueda ser modificado los inputs ?

Edit:
El formulario lo mando simplemente haciendo click en el boton registrarse:

```
document.querySelector(".Button-sc-qlcn5g-0.kHvryD").click()
```

Trate de hacer esto:

```
document.querySelector(".Button-sc-qlcn5g-0.kHvryD").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
  });
```

Pero aun asi se resetean los valores a los determinados.
Y el sitio por si es [www.spotify.com/signup](http://www.spotify.com/signup)

Comment: Es el comportamiento normal si el `input` está en un formulario por ejemplo. Considera usar [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: debes usar `event.preventDefault();` para evitar este comportamiento por defecto. en internet hay muchos ejemplos como [estos](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp).

Comment: Entiendo, deberia aplicar eso para cada input o para el formulario en sí ? Intente ambas pero aun asi se siguen reseteando los valores ante cualquier click en el sitio 

Comment: No para todos los elementos, sino en la función Javascript que escucha los clicks o los envíos de esos elementos. Ese dato falta en tu pregunta, por tanto no podemos decirte dónde debes ponerlo. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable.

Comment: Ahi edite el post con info sobre como hago click y como trate de hacer el preventDefault()

Comment: Alguno podrá ayudarme?

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas asociar la *escucha* del evento `submit` al formulario en donde se encuentra el botón, no al botón mismo. Para ello, puedes hacer uso del método [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), con el cual, ya teniendo ubicado el botón, puedes acceder al elemento más cercano al mismo que coincida con el parámetro que le pases, específicamente un selector CSS, que, en este caso, puede ser `form` o el identificador del formulario (si lo tuviera).

Eso sería más o menos así:

```javascript
const form = document.querySelector(".Button-sc-qlcn5g-0.kHvryD").closest("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

También podrías delegar el evento `submit` al documento y, mediante una estructura condicional, verificar si el elemento directamente afectado (que sería el formulario) es el formulario en cuestión, para lo cual te convendría emplear su identificador.

```javascript
document.addEventListener("submit", event => {
    if (event.target.id == "ID del formulario"){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

O bien puedes directamente tomar el formulario por su identificador y poner a *escuchar* el evento `submit` en él:

```javascript
const form = document.querySelector("#ID del formulario");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Tú decides cuál forma utilizar.

Un saludo